# Assist me in distinguishing between "elements of integration" and "differential".

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing why a differential is used for integrating when the partitions of a region of integration approach $0$.

When I was in calculus I solved differential equations and I also had to use differentials for integrating. So according to the material I am reviewing:

If $dx=1\Delta x$ is the differential of the function $x(x)=x$ and if $dy=f'(x)\Delta x$ is the differential of $y=f(x)$ then $dy=f'(x)dx$.

How should I continue to distinguish between differentials like used for arc length elements  $\int ds=\int |r'(t)|dt$ and differentials like in the single integral $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$ where the differential is, correct me if I am wrong, of $x(x)=x$.

*I just have to explain the element of integration I used: the element $ds$ is the differential of the function $s(t)=\int_{a}^{t}|r(u)|du$ so by the first fundamental theorem on calculus $s'(t)=|r'(t)|$ and $ds=|r'(t)|dt$ I used an Ohio State University edition of a James Stewart Calculus book & I am just fan of it...

Comment: By the way, when calculus is developed rigorously, in a book such as Calculus by Spivak or Understanding Analysis by Abbot, differentials are avoided entirely. They can be given a precise definition in more advanced parts of math, but this is not necessary for understanding calculus.

Comment: The notation $x(x) = x$ strikes me as bad notation, so you might try simply reading another book to learn calculus.